I have an Ethereum user address. I am wondering whether and how I can find out how much BTC this address holds
I have an Ethereum user address, say 0x3cc3ae64f26c8fa893358e5ae7717a0d001c0940. I am wondering whether and how I can find out how much BTC this address holds. I really appreciate your help!!!

Ethereum addresses are not compatible with BTC. One can't send BTC to an Ethereum address. So all Ethereum addresses hold zero BTC.

Thanks for your answers. I notice that pegged bitcoin such as WBTC may be helpful since pegged bitcoin is a map from BTC blockchain to Ethereum. For example, if an address in Ethereum holds 1 WBTC, it means that this address holds 1 BTC in BTC blockchain. Do I understand the concept of pegged bitcoin correctly? I really appreciate your help!

wrapped assets typically mean that the asset is locked in the source chain and minted in the destination chain. So the user doesn't own the BTC, but it's locked somewhere, and they are given a wBTC on ethereum
